# On Publishing Project VS12 , could not find 'bin\Debug\app.publish\setup.exe

Tags: c#, winforms

I completed my project on windows form, when I am going to publish the project it shows the error 
'bin\Debug\app.publish\setup.exe'. 
 and the setup file in the following path shows 'exclamation mark' on setup file. 
On security page it shows checked on "Enable ClickOnce Security Setting", when I unchecked it program built successfully but when I again going to publish it again checked it and shows the same error.

I have to deploy the project but this error don't allow me to publish project. Please anyone help me.

Comment: Can you include some screenshots?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dp8JMpWMUTcif1sexTmruhABZlk64eYe/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tliyoxpja6ZyyO11eBrSHk0PmkQ8PY4S/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you can check screenshot here

Comment: You say you need to deploy the project. For that you can just build it and take the necessary files. Can't you? You do not necessarily need to publish it. It is hard to follow your issue without the sequence of steps you undertook to get there.

Comment: From where I got the files? and which files?

Comment: Go to the location of your project on the hard-drive and find bin folder inside the root folder of the project. The .exe file in bin folder is your executable.